# Replace an existant file using Google Drive API V3

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to create a function that replace the content of the file referenced by **fileId** with a new content in **java.io.File newFileContent**. The following function update the content of the file with an empty content

```
public static void updateDriveFile(Drive service, java.io.File newFileContent, String fileId) {

    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File emptyContent = new File();
    emptyContent.setTrashed(true);
    service.files().update(fileId, emptyContent).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the content of a file from your file system before updating.

Please try this:

```
java.io.File newFileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename); 
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, newFileContent); 
File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
```